# remove duplicate list object with condition java

Tags: java, list, object

i have array list object, but i want to filter remove data if any duplicate id in one day.

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<UniqueCompletedChat> al = new ArrayList<UniqueCompletedChat>();
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-01", "D01"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-01", "D01"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-01", "D02"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-01", "D01"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-02", "D01"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-02", "D02"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-02", "D03"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-02", "D02"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-02", "D02"));
        al.add(new UniqueCompletedChat("2015-11-03", "D01"));

        List<UniqueCompletedChat> result = new ArrayList<UniqueCompletedChat>();
        Set<String> titles = new HashSet<String>();

        for (UniqueCompletedChat u : al) {
            if (titles.add(u.getIdDoctor()) || titles.add(u.getDate())) {
                result.add(u);
            }
        }

        for(UniqueCompletedChat u : result){
            System.out.print(u.getDate() + " || ");
            System.out.print(u.getIdDoctor());
            System.out.println("");
        }
}

class UniqueCompletedChat {
    private String date;
    private String idDoctor;

    public UniqueCompletedChat(String date, String idDoctor) {
        this.date = date;
        this.idDoctor = idDoctor;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getIdDoctor() {
        return idDoctor;
    }

    public void setIdDoctor(String idDoctor) {
        this.idDoctor = idDoctor;
    }
}
```

this is output from my code

[image]

my goal expectation result

[image]

how to reach my expectation? and any method elegantly to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bug come from this LOC:

```
if (titles.add(u.getIdDoctor()) || titles.add(u.getDate())) {
    result.add(u);
}
```

Try to combine and check it like this:

```
if (titles.add(u.getIdDoctor() + u.getDate())) {
    result.add(u);
}
```

Of course, you can use StringBuilder for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Doing it by hand (looping your array and figuring duplicates)
2. Using a Set, and adding equals(), hashcode() methods to your class UniqueCompletedChat that simply makes **two** chats that have the *same* date and doctor ... the *same* chat.

Basically you have to understand your "model" that guides your design. And, if in your model such two "chats" are "the same" when they happen on the same day, with the same doctor, then your implementation should reflect that.

And, talking about **good** design: don't use low-level abstractions. A date, is ... a **date**, not a **String**. Probably Java has **to many** different ways to deal with dates, calendars, time. But well: they are there. Pick one of those. Instead of moving around **Strings**. Same for "DoctorID": create a **class** that represents that thing.

Thing is: pushing around **Strings** might look convenient and easy to do; but it is the **opposite** of a good OO design. You know, if you don't care about using Javas type system; you could as well step back and do everything in a dynamic language instead of Java.

Comment: Java has only two ways to deal with date-time handling: (a) the troublesome, confusing, and flawed old way (java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, etc.), and (b) the modern clean powerful way in the java.time classes. Avoid any date-time class not in the java.time package.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on java 8

```
Collection<UniqueCompletedChat> result = al.stream()
                .<Map<String, UniqueCompletedChat>>collect(HashMap::new, (k, uc) -> k.put(uc.getKey(), uc), Map::putAll)
```

Just adding one method on your Chat class as :

```
public String getKey() {
    return this.idDoctor + this.date;
}
```

prints :

```
2015-11-02 || D02
2015-11-01 || D02
2015-11-02 || D03
2015-11-03 || D01
2015-11-02 || D01
2015-11-01 || D01
```

Comment: if using java 7 how to implement it?